# Phonegap download file from API not Server

Tags: cordova, api, download

I am developing a Phonegap/Cordova app and I was able to download a file and put it in the root folder of my phone using the FileTransfer plugin. The file was a simple image hosted on a server.

However, I am trying to download a file that is generated by my API (file is not hosted on the server). Once you hit the api, it returns a binary stream of file. This code works perfectly fine when done using AJAX in a browser but it does not work on my Android phone (testing). When I do this, I get error code 1.

If my URI is of a file hosted on the actual server, my fileTransfer.download works perfectly well.

My API that returns the file is in this format:

http://api.mydomainname.com/file/23

where 23 is file id.

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

var store;
var assetURL = encodeURI("http://api.mydomainname.com/file/23");
var fileName = "test.xlsx";

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotSys, fail);
}

function gotSys(fileSystem) {
    alert("Got FS");
    store = fileSystem.root;
    alert('Checking file: ' + store.toURL() + fileName);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store.toURL() + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);
}

function downloadAsset() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    alert("About to start transfer");
    fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store.toURL() + fileName,
        function (entry) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        function (err) {
            alert("Download error : " + err.code);
        });
}

function appStart() {
    alert('file exists');
    alert(store.toURL() + fileName);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("fail error: " + error);
}
```

My C# return that I tried (one of the tries) is:

```
response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(docData)); 

response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = doc.DocumentName; 
return response;
```

I tried to return binary, json (with file binary content), etc. Any suggestions? Is it even possible to download a file that's not hosted on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yura,
it is possible you have the *white-list* plugin issue. You need to add the *white-list* plugin to your App. On this you should also see the versions for you Compiler and your plugins.

See:

- [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)
- [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

You will also want to read.
*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md

- 10 Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.
- 6 Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler
- 7 Not setting "version" for you plugins

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: Thanks. I added the white-list permissions in my config.xml and also changed the URL from http to https and it seems to work. I will do more tests but thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One text box, submit button and another text box having a name and after clicking submit button, it should download a file as text file.

This is implemented using the below html code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
  <textarea name="text">Please download the text and see it carefully. </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want this to be implemented in cordova phonegap File Transfer Plugin..

This will help the user download the file which was created there itself.

Tried many places and could not get it.